# how can i check wrong id

Tags: visualforce, customer-community

how can i check wrong id

```
public with sharing class ContactDetailController {

    private ApexPages.StandardController standardController;
    public string conId{get;set;}


    public ContactDetailController(ApexPages.StandardController standardController) 
    {
       this.standardController = standardController;
       conId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
        if(standardController.getId()==null)
        {
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Please enter Id on the Address Bar'));
        }  
        //this.standardController.addFields(new List<String> {'FirstName','lastname','mobilephone','Accountid','otherphone','title','fax','Department','Email','Birthdate','AssistantName','Reportstoid','Assistantphone','leadsource','OtherStreet','MailingCity','othercity','MailingState','otherstate', });

        // getDescribe that retrive whole fields of the particular object
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = Contact.sObjectType.getDescribe();
        List<String>apiNames =  new list<String>();
        for(string apiName : r.fields.getMap().keySet()){
            apiNames.add(apiName);
        }
        System.debug(apiNames);
        this.standardController.addFields(apiNames);

    }
    public PageReference ValidateId()
    try{
               Id realContId = standardController.getId();
               if(Schema.Contact.SObjectType != realContId.getSobjectType())||
               {
                    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'Id specified is not an Contact id!'));
                    return null;
               }
         }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'Bad id specified!'));
           return null; 
        }
}

    public PageReference Edit()
    {
        PageReference errorPage = new PageReference('/apex/ContactInsert?id='+conId);
        errorPage.setRedirect(true);
        return errorPage;
    }  
    public PageReference cloneButton()
    {
        // Record being cloned
        Contact con = (Contact) standardController.getRecord(); 
        // Custom clone logic
        Contact clonedcon = new Contact();
        clonedcon.FirstName = con.FirstName;
        clonedcon.lastName = con.lastName; 
        clonedcon.mobilephone = con.mobilephone;
        clonedcon.Accountid = con.Accountid;
        clonedcon.otherphone = con.otherphone;
        clonedcon.title = con.title;
        clonedcon.fax = con.fax;
        clonedcon.Department = con.Department;
        clonedcon.Email = con.Email;
        clonedcon.Birthdate = con.Birthdate;
        clonedcon.AssistantName = con.AssistantName; 
        clonedcon.Reportstoid = con.Reportstoid;
        clonedcon.Assistantphone = con.Assistantphone;
        clonedcon.leadsource = con.leadsource;
        clonedcon.OtherStreet= con.OtherStreet;
        clonedcon.MailingCity = con.MailingCity;
        clonedcon.othercity = con.othercity;
        clonedcon.MailingState = con.MailingState;
        clonedcon.otherstate = con.otherstate;
        clonedcon.MailingPostalCode = con.MailingPostalCode;
        clonedcon.otherpostalcode = con.otherpostalcode;
        clonedcon.MailingCountry = con.MailingCountry; 
        clonedcon.othercountry = con.othercountry;
        clonedcon.Languages__c = con.Languages__c;
        clonedcon.Level__c = con.Level__c;
        clonedcon.Description= con.Description;

        insert clonedcon;
        PageReference errorPage = new PageReference('/apex/ContactInsert?id='+conId);

        errorPage.setRedirect(true);
        return errorPage;


        //return new PageReference('/' +clonedcon.id+ '/e' );
        // Redirect to the new cloned record
        //return new PageReference('/'+clonedcon.Id);
        return null;
    }

}
```

getting error

> Id value 0012800000CyJVI is not valid for the Contact standard
>   controller

is there any way to check my Id is correct or not. and show error in VF page using `apex:pagemessage`

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange, Sachin. Your question is very vague. What is the actual problem? Are you getting an error? Which ID? When? Why? You need to fill in some details, otherwise you are unlikely to get help. Please read the help topic on how to ask a question and then edit your question above to include more details: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ids that start with 001 are Accounts, not Contacts

Answer (score 1):

**- Updated to contain page messaging -**

You can give this a try. It should validate your Id for you:

```
public Id validateId(String potentialId) {
    return (potentialId instanceOf Id) ? (Id)potentialId : null;
}
```

Alternately if you want to validate by SObject type, which might be a little bit better, security wise:

```
public Id validateIdByType(String potentialId, SObjectType desiredType) {
    Id parsedId = (potentialId instanceOf Id) ? (Id)potentialId : null;

    if (parsedId == null || parsedId.getSObjectType() != desiredType) {
        return null;
    }

    return parsedId;
}
```

If you want to use page messaging you can do this somewhere in another method. In the original question it looks like it would be the constructor.

```
Id contactId = validateIdByType(ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('Id'), Contact.getSObjectType());

if (contactId == null) {
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'Invalid Id provided. Please check your input and try again.'));
}
```

Just be sure to include  in your page or component.

From either of these you should be able to determine if the result is null and progress from there. Hope this helps!

Comment: is there any way to check my Id is correct or not. and show error in VF page using `apex:pagemessage` ?

Comment: @Ratan I have updated the above to add a page message. As you mentioned, be sure to include <apex:pageMessages /> in your visualforce page or component.

Comment: Rocnick try with standardcontroller in VF page and try to catch exception in controller